# friend list in facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to fetch friend list. I wrote following code..

```
$friends = $this->facebook->api('me/friends');
echo count($friends);
```

Answer was 1. (though it should have been 456). What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data structure returned by the API is different than you think.
Try `echo count($friends['data']);` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much... I often get stuck up at stupidest places :)